# Having trouble returning C returning array

Tags: c

I declare hws globally and try to return it in this method but I get a pointer error.  I was wondering if anyone knew why that is and could suggest a solution?  Randomize just get a random number.

```
extern int hws[100][20];

int randomize()
{

    int value;
    int tru_fals = 0;
    value = -1;
    while ( tru_fals != 1 )
    {
        value = rand();
        if ( 0 < value )
        {
            if( 101 > value )
            {
                tru_fals = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return value;

}
int *populate()
{

    int i, j;

    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    while( i < 20 )
    {
        while ( j < 100)
        {
            int temp = randomize();
            hws[i][j] = temp;
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return hws;

}
```

Comment: `hws` is not an array. it's an array of arrays.

Comment: If it's global, why return it? Just access it everywhere...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof`, `_Alignof`, or unary `&` operator, or is a string literal being used to initialize another array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and its value will be the address of the first element in the array ([6.3.2.1/3](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)).

In the line `return hws;` in `populate`, the type of the expression `hws` is "100-element array of 20-element array of `int`"; by the rule above, it will be converted to type "pointer to 20-element array of `int`", or `int (*)[20]`.  Thus, the correct declaration for `populate` would need to be

```
int (*populate())[20]
{
   ...
   return hws;
}
```

which reads as

```
      populate           -- populate
      populate()         -- is a function
     *populate()         -- returning a pointer
    (*populate())[20]    -- to a 20-element array
int (*populate())[20]    -- of int.
```

and the type of whatever you return the result to would need to be `int (*)[20]` as well.

Having said that...

Using global variables this way is highly discouraged for a number of reasons.  It would be better to pass the array in to `populate` as a parameter, like so:

```
void populate(int (*arr)[20], size_t rows)
{  
  size_t i, j;

  for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
  {
    for (j = 0; j < 20; j++)
    {
      arr[i][j] = randomize();
    }
  }
}
```

You would call this as simply

```
populate(hws, sizeof hws / sizeof hws[0]);
```

If you're using a compiler that supports variable length arrays (either a C99 compiler or a C2011 compiler that does not define `__STDC_NO_VLA__` or defines it to 0), you could define the function as

```
void populate(size_t cols, size_t rows, int (*arr)[cols]) // cols must be declared
{                                                         // before it can be used
  size_t i, j;                                            // to declare arr

  for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
  {
    for (j = 0; j < cols; j++)
    {
      arr[i][j] = randomize();
    }
  }
}
```

and call it as

```
size_t rows = sizeof hws[0] / sizeof hws[0][0];  // dividing the size of the array
size_t cols = sizeof hws / sizeof hws[0];        // by the size of the first element
populate(cols, rows, hws);                       // gives the number of elements
```

so you're not hardcoding the 20 anywhere.

If you aren't using a compiler that supports variable length arrays, and you don't want to hardcode the number of rows in the function prototype, you can do something like this:

```
void populate(int *arr, size_t rows, size_t cols)
{
  size_t i, j;
  for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
  {
    for (j = 0; j < cols; j++)
    {
      arr[i * rows + j] = randomize();
    }
  }
}
```

and call it as

```
// rows and cols calculated as above
populate(&hws[0][0], rows, cols);
```

In this case, instead of passing a pointer to the array, we pass a pointer to the first element (the address value is the same, but the type is `int *` instead of `int (*)[20]`.  So the `populate` function treats it like a 1D array, and computes the offset with `i * rows + j`.  Note that this trick will only work for 2D arrays that have been allocated contiguously.

This also means that `populate` can work with arrays of any size, not just Nx20.

Answer (score 2):

You define `extern int hws[100][20];`.
This doesn't create any array. It just says that somewhere in the program, there should be one.

To make it work, some other source file must really define the array - `int hws[100][20];` (without `extern`). Then, if you compile both and link together, it should work.

If you only want one source file, it's much easier - just remove `extern`.

**But:** Just noticed [Serge's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12518852/1111371), which is actually the real cause of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

there is a bug: the array is declared as 100x20 but then you iterate through it like it is 20x100.

Answer (score 0):

hws is a matrix, it means that its and int **

You are returning and int * so you are having a pointer type mismatch.

Comment: You're wrong here. A matrix isn't an array of arrays, it's just a bunch of integers (2000 in this case). When returning it, it decays to `int *`, not `int **`.

Comment: You're both wrong.  `hws` decays to `int (*)[20]` (pointer to 20-element array of `int`).

Answer (score 0):

First, it doesn't need to be returned since it's global. Second, it is a pointer to a pointer to an int. It's an array of an array.